# Counting substrings that belong to a regular language

Tags: algorithms, regular-languages, counting

Given a regular language $L$ and a string $x$ give an efficient algorithm to count the occurrences of substrings $x[i,j] \in L$.

More in particular, I am looking for a linear time algorithm in the length of the string $|x|$, for a given deterministic automaton $M$ accepting the language $L$.

This question is meant to generalize the question of counting substrings where each symbol occurs an even number of times, asked before [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136218/4287).

Comment: Assuming the language $L$ is specified by a DFA, it can be done in $O(n^2)$ time with a trivial algorithm: for each $i$, run the DFA over $x[i,n]$, counting the number of times it hits an accept state, and sum up these counts.  I don't know whether it is possible to do better.

Comment: @D.W. Indeed, I strongly believe that this is possible in linear time, I should perhaps have added that. That is, linear time in the length of $x$, for a fixed regular $L$.

Comment: Can we assume the regular language is available as a DFA?

Comment: Assume that $L$ is a regular language over the alphabet $\Sigma$. Then the language $M=\Sigma^*L$ is also regular. So, you can build an DFA for $M$ and pass $x$ through it. Every time a final state is reached one has found a substring that is in $L$.

Comment: See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642303000133)

Comment: @HendrikJan, could you make it clear that the specification of $L$ can be treated as a constant? That is, we are looking for an algorithm that is efficient with respect to the size of the string $x$. Otherwise, it is unlikely there is a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: @plop That seems to work. Not the solution I had in mind, but from what I understand equivalent to it. Perhaps we need a simple construction for the automaton for $\Sigma^* L$ given an automaton for $L$?

Comment: The paper in the link above (which I had not read when I posted it) mentions `A.V. Aho, Algorithms for Finding Patterns in Strings, vol. A, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1990,pp. 257–300` as a reference for the approach that consists of constructing a DFA for the language $\Sigma^*L$. The paper linked itself actually gives a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in $O(|x|\cdot |M|)$ with dynamic programming.

Let $q_0$ be the starting state, $\delta$ the transition function of $M$, and $a(q) \to \{0, 1\}$ a boolean function indicating whether $q$ is an accepting state in $M$.

Let $A[i, q]$ be the number of non-empty prefixes of $x_ix_{i+1}\ldots x_n$ accepted by $M$ if we start in state $q$. We can directly compute $A[n, q] = a(\delta(q, x_n))$. Then, going backwards row by row, we can fill the table using $A[i,q] = a(\delta(q, x_{i})) + A[i+1, \delta(q, x_{i})]$.

Finally, you sum $a(q_0) +\sum_{i=1}^nA[i, q_0]$ as your answer, as this is the sum over all non-empty prefixes of all non-empty suffixes, plus one if the empty string is accepted, thus all substrings.